# PCLStorage.FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage is incomplete

Tags: local-storage, launcher

I use Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview
Version 17.9.0 Preview 3.0

In an UWP app I use:
IFolder folder = PCLStorage.FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
folder =
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local...
instead of
C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Packages/bc...k6/LocalCache/Local/...
Launcher.OpenAsync cannot find the file.

How can I get the complete folder from PCLStorage?